# Killing a process with C program

Tags: c, linux

I'm writing a program that open a .txt file by vim and whenever i press CTRL+C the process will be killed. But the thing is i can't find the process's pid that i've just created and kill it. Can anybody help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void ctrl_C(int sig){
    system("kill -9 $(pidof id)");
    printf("\n You pressed Ctrl + C,Good Bye \n");
    exit(0);    
}



int main(){
    printf("I am Programmer \n");
    pid_t id = system("gnome-terminal -- vi abcd.txt"); 
    signal(SIGINT,ctrl_C);
    while(1){}
    
}
```

Comment: Please post code as code, not images.

Comment: regarding:  `system("kill -9 $(pidof id)");`  much better to use:a statement like: `int kill(pid_t pid, int sig);`

Comment: regarding: `printf("\n You pressed Ctrl + C,Good Bye \n");`  There is  a long array of C functions that should not be called in a signal handler function.  `printf()` is such a function.  Suggest using `write( 1, "\n You pressed Ctrl + C,Good Bye \n", sizeof( "\n You pressed Ctrl + C,Good Bye \n" ) );`

Comment: If you want to manipulate the child, don't use `system`.  `fork/exec` the process instead.

Comment: Do you know that there's a `kill(2)` system call available that allows you to kill a process without the need to call an external command?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple issues with your code:

- `system(3)` does NOT return PID of child process, but instead waits for it to exit, and returns its exit code. You need to use the traditional fork+exec approach.
- With child PID available, it's easier to call `kill(2)` than `kill(1)`
- Better add `sleep` in a dead loop waiting for input. This reduces CPU load and your electricity bill.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

pid_t child_id;

void ctrl_C(int sig){
    kill(child_id, 9);
    printf("\n You pressed Ctrl + C,Good Bye \n");
    exit(0);    
}



int main(){
    printf("I am Programmer \n");
    pid_t child_id = fork();
    if (child_id == 0) {
        execlp("gnome-terminal", "gnome-terminal", "--", "vi", "abcd.txt", NULL);
        return 255;
    }
    signal(SIGINT,ctrl_C);
    while (1) {
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you but when i press CTRL + C, it says KILLED but the process still hang on. is it a zombie process, how do i kill it

Comment: When a process handles SIGINT, it needs to in the handler to clear the handler and then kill itself with the same signal.

Comment: See [Proper handling of SIGINT/SIGQUIT](https://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html)

Comment: `exit(0);` should be replaced with `signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL); kill(getpid(), SIGINT);`

Comment: i don't know if it is me or the method seems off but i tried your method and other but it'doesn't seem working great, the process just keep hanging

Comment: I'm not good at Linux but shouldn't this rather be `system("sleep infinity");` or some such? Otherwise the process keeps waking up, yeah? Even though the sleep() might cause it to yield its time slice. Windows has `Sleep(INFINITE);`.

Comment: @Lundin That's not true infinity. The sleep command calls this actually: `clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=2073600, tv_nsec=999999999}, NULL)`

Comment: Regardless, that ought to be better solution than waking up every second?

Comment: the functions `kill()` and `signal()` should not be called within a signal handler function. read [signal-safety](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)